# Having trouble reading file into vector

Tags: c++

I have a file that has three ints on three rows. It looks like this:

> 000
>   001
>   010

And I'm trying to read each integer into the vector positions but I don't know if I'm doing it right. Here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> numbers;
   std::fstream out("out.txt");

   std::copy(std::ostreambuf_iterator<int>(out.rdbuf()),
             std::ostreambuf_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(numbers));
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm getting a "no matching function call" error on the line where I do the copy.

Comment: ostreambuf_iterator is a class for writing characters. Doesn't seem appropriate to your requirements (which is reading after all). Have you tried just writing a regular for loop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### You're using wrong iterator.

You need `istreambuf_iterator`, not `ostreambuf_iterator`:

```
 std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<int>(out.rdbuf()),
           std::istreambuf_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(numbers));
```

Note that `ostreambuf_iterator` is an output iterator. It is used to *write*, not *read*. What you want to do is, *read* for which you need `istreambuf_iterator`.

#### But wait!  The above code is not going to work either, Why?

Because you're using `istreambuf_iterator` and passing `int` to it.  The `istreambuf_iterator` reads data as *unformatted buffer* of type either `char*` or `wchar_t*`. The template argument to `istreambuf_iterator` could be either `char` or `wchar_t`.

What you actually need is called `istream_iterator` which reads *formatted* data of given type:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(out), //changed here also!
          std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(numbers));
```

This will work great now.

Note that you could just avoid using `std::copy`, and use the constructor of `std::vector` itself as:

```
std::fstream in("out.txt");

std::vector<int> numbers((std::istream_iterator<int>(in)), //extra braces
                         std::istream_iterator<int>());
```

Note the extra braces around first argument which is used to avoid *vexing parse* in C+++.

If the vector object is already created (and optionally it has some elements in it), then you can *still* avoid `std::copy` as:

```
numbers.insert(numbers.end(), 
               std::istream_iterator<int>(in), //no extra braces
               std::istream_iterator<int>());
```

No extra braces needed in this case.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I still don't think this will be what the OP is after, although he does seem very confused. I'm guess he wants to end up with a vector containing zeros and ones, but this code won't give him that.

Comment: I'm still getting an error "no matching function call" on that line.

Comment: @user2030677 You probably need `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: @john: He mentioned `000` is one int. Read the first line in the question.

Comment: +1 for explanation of `istreambuf_iterator`. I just thought it looked unnecessary and used `istream_iterator`.

Comment: @Nawaz Is the most vexing parse really relevant, here? Assuming we don't have a type called `in`, I don't see how this could be parsed as a function declaration.

Comment: @Agentlien: See, that is why I didn't call it *most* vexing parse, I called it only *vexing parse*. The `in` there becomes a name of the parameter. Note that `int f(int x)` is same as `int f(int (x))`. That is, the braces around `x` are superfluous, same is the case with `in`. See it without the braces, things will become clear to you.

Comment: @Nawaz Right.. I forgot that gotcha.. This is why I'm glad we have the uniform initialization since C++11.. Now we can just use {} and not worry about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Read the Book 'C++ How To Program' by Dietal & Dietal, The chapter on Vectors. I assure you, all your problems will be solved. You have opened the text file for output instead of input.     Instead of using this function I would suggest that you should read-in strings and copy them into your vector using iterators until EOF is encountered in the file. EDIT: This way is more natural and easy to read and understand if you are new to Vectors.